# How to add text via loop in pdfkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, node-pdfkit

I want to create an PDF document with orderitems in pdfkit.

So I created an pdf document with some information like buyer and sender like this way:

```
doc = new pdf({autoFirstPage: false});
doc.addPage({
    margin: 50
});
doc.text(shipTo.name, 50);
doc.moveDown(0.5);
doc.text(shipTo.address + " " + shipTo.number + shipTo.addition ? shipTo.addition : "");
doc.moveDown(0.3);
doc.text(shipTo.zip)
doc.moveDown(0.3);
doc.text(shipTo.city);
doc.moveDown(0.3);
doc.text(shipTo.country);
```

But now I want to show some information about the ordered products. I have created a loop through order.items, which also looks in the products collection, but nothing is showing up in de PDF, but in the console I see the information I need to print.

```
for(var i = 0; i < order.items.length; i++){
    var item = order.items[i];
    Product.findOne({_id: order.items[i].productId}).exec(function(err, product){
        console.log(item.name, item.quantity, product.eanCode);
        doc.moveDown();
        doc.text(item.name, 50);
        doc.moveUp();
        doc.text(product.eanCode, 300);
        doc.moveUp();
        doc.text(item.quantity, 500);
    })
}
```

Has anybody an idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show what is in your order.items because i think you only need the name of which is your key in order.items.

Show your array for a little bit clarification

For eg:-

```
var arr = ["foo","moo","bar","xyz","abc"];

   var margin = 150;
   var serialNo = 1;
     for(var i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
      doc.text(serialNo++,50,margin)
      doc.text(arr[i],100,margin)
      margin = margin + 20;
  }
```

Here is a quick example which you can refer.. :)